# Какая логика у JavaScript в Математике?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Почему JavaScript считает что

0-600= -599

0+600= 599
???

Что я сделал не так?

```
<script>
        function validate() {
            // get the input
            var x = document.forms["input_form"]["aterm1"].value;
            var y = document.forms["input_form"]["aterm2"].value;

            // output the result (or errors)
            document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = "<h>" + (x +++ 600) + ", " + (y +++ 600) + "</h>";
            document.getElementById("2").innerHTML = "<h>" + (x --- 600) + ", " + (y --- 600) + "</h>";
            document.getElementById("4").innerHTML = "<h>" + (x +++ 600) + ", " + (y --- 600) + "</h>";
            document.getElementById("3").innerHTML = "<h>" + (x --- 600) + ", " + (y +++ 600) + "</h>";
        }

    </script>
```

[image: 1]

Comment: Лучше расскажите, что такое математический знак три плюса `+++` и математический знак три минуса `---`, отсюда и будет ответ на вопрос.

Comment: Если написать + или - , то JS он не будет производить вычисление.
Но если попробовать +++ или ---, то вычисления выходит, но с ошибками.

Comment: Если написать просто `+` или `-`, то вычисления производиться будут, если вы только еще где-то не допустите ошибку. А вот `+++` выливается в другие операции - постфиксный инкремент, которым увеличивает значение в `x` и `y` на единицу после вычисления. Поэтому `(x +++ 600)` читается как `((x++) + 600)` где `++` - инкремент.

Comment: Где тут ошибка? Программа выводит 
**1.** 0600, 0600
**2.** -600, -600
**3.** 0600, -600
**4.** -600, 0600


`document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = "<h>" + (x + 600) + ", " + (y + 600) + "</h>";`
          `document.getElementById("2").innerHTML = "<h>" + (x - 600) + ", " + (y - 600) + "</h>";`
          `document.getElementById("4").innerHTML = "<h>" + (x + 600) + ", " + (y - 600) + "</h>";`
           `document.getElementById("3").innerHTML = "<h>" + (x - 600) + ", " + (y + 600) + "</h>";}

Comment: Когда вы читаете значение из input, то получаете не число, а строку. Если из строки вычесть число, будет нормальная операция `600 - "1" = 599`. А вот если прибавить, то он склеит их как строки `600 + "1" = "6001"`. Используйте `parseInt()` для приведения к числу, ответ уже дали.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Операторов `+++` и `---` в `javascript` нет. Такая записать воспринимается как `++ +`.

Чтобы корректно посчитать, то что вам надо, нужно спарсить из строки `value` в целочисленный тип `int`, функцией `parseInt(string, base)`.

Вот пример в вашем случае:

```js
function validate() {
  // get the input
  var x = parseInt(document.forms["input_form"]["aterm1"].value, 10);
  //Если пользователь ничего не ввел, то дефолт значение = 0
  if(isNaN(x)) x = 0;
  var y = parseInt(document.forms["input_form"]["aterm2"].value, 10);
  if(isNaN(y)) y = 0;

  // output the result (or errors)
  document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = "<h>" + (x + 600) + ", " + (y + 600) + "</h>";
  document.getElementById("2").innerHTML = "<h>" + (x - 600) + ", " + (y - 600) + "</h>";
  document.getElementById("4").innerHTML = "<h>" + (x + 600) + ", " + (y - 600) + "</h>";
  document.getElementById("3").innerHTML = "<h>" + (x - 600) + ", " + (y + 600) + "</h>";
}
```

```html
<form id="input_form">
<input id="aterm1">
<input id="aterm2">

<p id="1">
</p>
<p id="2">
</p>
<p id="3">
</p>
<p id="4">
</p>

<input type="button" onclick="validate()" value="Click">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Логика простая просто нужно немного получить JavaScript, а точнее преобразования типов. У вас в инпутах лежать строки, чтоб были числа нужно их преобразовать в число.

```js
let x = '0';
console.log((x)+++600);
x= (+'0')+600;
console.log(x);
x= '0'+600;
console.log(x);
```